# Java. Как изменить метод, чтоб суммировались только те елементы произведение индексов которых равняется 5

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int m1[][] =  {{1,2,3,4,5},{1,1,2}};
int m2[][] = {{1,2,3},{5,6,4}};    
    System.out.println(sumArray(m1,m2));


}
public static int sumArray(int[][]... args ){
 int sum = 0;
 for(int s=0; s<args.length; s++){

     int a[][]= args[s];

   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            sum += a[i][j];
        }
   }
 }
    return sum;           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если я правильно понял ваш вопрос то скорее всего так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m1[][] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5}};
    int m2[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 4}};
    System.out.println(sumArray(m1, m2));
}

private static int sumArray(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1[i].length; j++) {
            if (i * j == 5)
                sum += m1[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m2[i].length; j++) {
            if (i * j == 5)
                sum += m2[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```